# write a python script to run gdb and interact with gdb?

Tags: python, subprocess, gdb

I want to use python to write a script, run gdb in python, and run a c++ program in gdb, c++ program "a.out" will output  `hello world!! xxxx2xxxx3`, or will raise exception with "free(): xxxxxx", I want to catch the key world "free()" in python and use gdb `backtrace` to find where the problem is.

```py
def run():
    command = ['gdb', '--args', './a.out', '2', '3']
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    #process.stdin.write(b'handle SIGABRT stop\n')
    process.stdin.flush() 
    process.stdin.write(b'run\n')  
    process.stdin.flush()
    
    output = process.communicate()[1]  
    print(output)
    if b'free():' in output:  
         print("Program output 'free():'. Not exiting gdb.")  
         return True  
    else:  
         print("Program output does not contain 'free():'. Exiting gdb.")  
         process.stdin.write(b'quit\n')  
         process.stdin.flush()  
         return False  
     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

After I run this python script, the output as below:

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) Starting program: a.out 2 3
hello world!!
xxxx2xxxx3
[Inferior 1 (process 98823) exited normally]
(gdb) quit
b''
Program output does not contain 'free():'. Exiting gdb.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtest.py", line 157, in <module>
    run6()
  File "runtest.py", line 134, in run6
    process.stdin.write(b'quit\n')  
ValueError: write to closed file
```

I expect I can control gdb when to `quit`; Dont know why gdb always `quit` before `print(output)`, So I have no time to input `backtrace` in gdb

Comment: `output` is empty, doesn't gdb write to stdout instead of stderr?

Comment: GDB will output `quit` and then exit when it tries to read from a closed stdin, which is what happens when you use `Popen.communicate`. If you want 
 to have dynamic interaction with a subprocess, maybe `Popen` can be made to do that, but it might be better to use the [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module.